# Get local time difference from GMT on Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, timezone

I can get a list of the timezones available to Windows Phone 8 device using the following.

```
TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones()
```

But how would i get a list of the time difference of the zones from a base time, i.e. GMT? I want to find out what the time difference is so I can set the alarm accordingly on the local device timezone.

The local time zone is set to UK, but the user wants to set the alarm in timezone Indian.

My app needs to work out the hours difference from the system time from the timezone selected. So I can set the devices alarm time to their local time, but that it is correct for the time zone selected.

Comment: Could you give more details about exactly what you're trying to achieve? It's not clear at the moment. There are plenty of methods to convert between one time zone and another.

Comment: @JonSkeet Please see more detail in question thanks

Comment: @JonSkeet so in esssnce i need to find the difference between the timezone slected and the devices current timezone much same way skype does

Comment: Don't you just need to convert the alarm time from one zone to the other? I don't think you need the difference...

Comment: @JonSkeet but if i just set the alarm to the timezone  time would it not be in acurate could you provide an example plz

Comment: Why would it be inaccurate? Have you looked at the methods in TimeZoneInfo?

Comment: @JonSkeet can u please povide an example plz

Comment: No, because you still haven't explained the problem clearly - in particular, I really don't think you need to know the *difference* between two time zones. Also, you still haven't shown any sign of research into what `TimeZoneInfo` provides, or any sample code to illustrate what you're trying to do.

Comment: Start by looking at the [TimeZoneInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.timezoneinfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class and check out which methods and properties are available.

Comment: @Murphy - you might also look at [the timezone tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info), and you should realize that the difference between two time zones is highly dependent on a particular moment in time.  The answer will change depending on *when* you are talking about.